# Open a program with a script in python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pywin32

I'm trying to find a way where I can open a especific program on my computer and do some clicks to download a report from executing a script with python, I found this:

```
import os
import subprocess

command = "cmd"
subprocess.Popen(command)
```

I tried with the code above but nothing happened, any idea if this can be done? library that can help me? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing your current working directory to directory where that software is install by this code
//Code
`import os`
`os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files\[Application Folder]\")`

And then change
command = "application_name.exe"

This will open the application

After this you have to use pyautogui module for automating clicks